# Add elements in the DOM with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to print in the HTML the data from another part of the site, the data appears on the console, however not in the HTML.

I believe it is an error in the code, could someone point me or direct me?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://example.com',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (json) {
        var reservas = json;

        reservas.forEach(function (reserva) {
            $(".reservas").append($("<td/>", {
                html: reserva
            }));

            console.log(reserva);
        });
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

If i change the variable reservas for:

```
var reservas = ["test", "test2", "test3"]
```

And the elements are being added..

when I give `console.log (reserve)`, the console return:

```
Object {
  _id: "10152686662737642",
  nome: "First Person",
  email: "email1@gmail.com",
  __v: 0
}(index):68
Object {
  _id: "10152433045473800",
  nome: "Second Person",
  email: "email2@gmail.com",
  __v: 0
} (index):68
```

maybe the problem is that is not an array?

Comment: Does `$('.reservas')` select anything?

Comment: What have you done to debug the problem? Is the success callback called? Is the error callback called? Since we can't run the code, you have to provide more information, otherwise we can't really help you.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, please add the tag to your question.

Comment: Use your debugger to check which branch is executed, the error or the success and check if ".reservas" actually selects anything rest of the code looks fine.

Comment: You are trying to console.log(reserve), but you don't have any `reserve` object in your code. Do you mean `reserva`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your clarifications. I believe what you want to do is:

```
$(".reservas").append($("<td/>", {
    html: JSON.stringify(reserva)
}));
```

either that or $(".reservas") isn't finding any elements in the DOM. Also you may want to do something like:

```
$(".reservas").append($("<td/>", {
    html: reserva.nome + "  " + reserva.email
}));
```

instead depending on what you actually want to display

Comment: THANKS MAN, I LOVE U! hahaha <3

Comment: No problem :) if it is the correct answer can you please accept the answer(The checkmark under this post, on the left) and upvote it if you found it useful :)

Comment: Of course i can haha =D..

i cant vote because i don't have reputation, but i already accept the answer =)